# android.util.Base64 encode/decode flags parameter

Tags: java, android, base64

According to the Javadoc, android.util.Base64.decode() takes two parameters: the text, and "flags". These flags are in int form and (I quote):

`flags  controls certain features of the decoded output. Pass DEFAULT to decode standard Base64.`

First off, thanks to whomever decided to write a vague Javadoc. I see that Base64 has some enumeration strings, and in practice, we have been using Base64.NO_WRAP as our flag. In this particular instance, however, we need to employ two flags: NO_WRAP, and URL_SAFE.

How do we specify both flags? We tried separating them with a pipe ('|'), and that didn't do it.

```
import android.util.Base64;
public class Foo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String urlSafeBase64EncodedString = getUrlSafeBase64EncodedString();
        int flags = ????????; //Need both Base64.NO_WRAP and Base64.URL_SAFE
        String decodedString = Base64.decode(urlSafeBase64EncodedString, flags);
    }
}
```

Thanks for your time.

Comment: "that didn't do it" - so what did it do? (And what *exactly* did you write?) If you're going to complain about others being vague, it helps to be precise yourself :)

Comment: It didn't do anything. It failed to decode the Base64 string. I already said, I separated two flags with a pipe symbol...how is that not clear exactly?

Comment: It was entirely possible that you'd got the syntax wrong, as "Base64.NO_WRAP | URL_SAFE" for example. That would have given a compilation error, of course... which would have been covered by "that didn't do it" too. Now "It didn't do anything" and "It failed to decode the Base64 string" aren't exactly the same thing. *How* did it fail to decode it? Was there an exception, did it give empty results, did it hang?

Comment: Separated with a pipe like `int flags = Base64.NO_WRAP | Base64.URL_SAFE;` ?  And I think @jonskeet was wondering if decode() threw an exception, return the string unchanged, did one of the flags but not the other, etc.

Comment: I just checked the code https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/util/Base64.java This does exactly what you would expect it to do. If it did not fulfill your expectations it's not because its ambiguous or ill documented in anyway. Describe more the output you are looking for and maybe we can help you. But the usual NO_WRAP | URL_SAFE works as expected.

Comment: @JonSkeet sorry for getting snippy. No exceptions were thrown: The string simply was not decoded.

Comment: @MahdeTo That's just it. I read the Javadoc. It IS vague. It doesn't explain how to pass in two flags, and doesn't mention if it's even possible. Checking the source code is not the same as reading the doc. Anyway, I looked at the source code, and personally couldn't decipher how it worked. I get that pipe is doing a bitwise OR, but since the javadoc doesn't say anything about it, I'm not sure if that's what I'm supposed to be doing.

Comment: @CodyS Thats how flags usually work a concept inherited from the c days, it is kind of the defacto standard and 9 out of 10 libs won't mention it, anyways :) you live and you learn! Happy Flagging :)

Comment: @MahdeTo and, I learn something new. We'll give that a shot. In the meantime, if you Post an answer to this page, assuming it works, I'll Mark it as correct. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

int flags passed to functions are usually defined to be bitwise ORed to achieve a combined effect.

You can usually tell by looking at the constant values, they would go 0 1 2 4 8 16 ..

As for your question you can use the following for your flag definition:

```
int flags = Base64.NO_WRAP | Base64.URL_SAFE;
```

Comment: I'm going to have to write a very stern letter to my CS professors for never making this clear. Gonna file this away for later. Worked great! Thank you!

Comment: if I need  "base64 for use in <img>"  what would be the Equivalent flag or flags  in android?

Answer (score 7):

For `kotlin` you can use

```
val flag = Base64.URL_SAFE or Base64.NO_WRAP
```