# What does the number mean in Base64.encodeToString(data, number)?

Tags: java, android

I saw a lot of java encoding lately with lines like:

`Base64.encodeToString(data, 0);`

`Base64.encodeToString(data, 2);`

What does the number mean really? I suspect the 0 is default or false, and what does the 2 mean? Maybe it is the same as `Base64.encodeToString(data, Base64.NO_WRAP)`?

Comment: See [the API documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Base64.html). The constant `NO_WRAP` has the value 2, so the answer to your second question is: yes. 0 means the same as `Base64.DEFAULT`. It's all in the documentation.

Comment: You could check it out following solution : [Base64 flag parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9436103/android-util-base64-encode-decode-flags-parameter)

Comment: Law of the minimum effort....

Comment: @Jesper, but why did they output different value? I also saw things like `Base64.encodeToString(data, 0, length, Base64.NO_WRAP)` before. Does the number mean starting position or ending position? Or perhaps only the first x characters?

Comment: Did you look at the [API documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Base64.html)? (<= That's a link to the documentation, click it). It explains exactly what the methods you are talking about do and what the parameters mean.

Comment: @Hackerman well I usually check the documentation before I ask a question. In this case the outputs are different so I thought I didn't understand the doc.

Comment: @JamesWayne The output is different because each flag has a specific purpose. The output differs wrt it.

Comment: @Jesper yes I read it multiple times. I don't think it explained or maybe I didn't understand.

Comment: @PankajSinghal but didn't the documentation say 2 = no_wrap?

Comment: @JamesWayne Yes. As Jesper said, the answer to your second question is: yes. It is no_wrap

Comment: @PankajSinghal then why did `Base64.encodeToString(data, 2)` not match with `Base64.encodeToString(data, Base64.NO_WRAP)`?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned here in the [doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Base64.html#encodeToString(byte[],%20int)), you can pass the following flags. Each explained with its meaning.

```
int CRLF -> Encoder flag bit to indicate lines should be terminated with a CRLF pair instead of just an LF.
int DEFAULT -> Default values for encoder/decoder flags.
int NO_CLOSE -> Flag to pass to Base64OutputStream to indicate that it should not close the output stream it is wrapping when it itself is closed.
int NO_PADDING -> Encoder flag bit to omit the padding '=' characters at the end of the output (if any).
int NO_WRAP -> Encoder flag bit to omit all line terminators (i.e., the output will be on one long line).
int URL_SAFE -> Encoder/decoder flag bit to indicate using the "URL and filename safe" variant of Base64 (see RFC 3548 section 4) where - and _ are used in place of + and /.
```

Comment: but why did they output different value? I also saw things like `Base64.encodeToString(data, 0, length, Base64.NO_WRAP)` before. Does the number mean starting position or ending position? Or perhaps only the first x characters?

Comment: `encodeToString(byte[] input, int offset, int len, int flags)` -> As the arguments mention, the 2nd arg is where you start. The third arg is the len till which the string is encoded starting from offset. Rest is same as the method without the offset & len. The default method `encodeToString(byte[] input, int flags)` encodes whole string

Comment: Okay so `Base64.encodeToString(data, 2)` is really not `Base64.encodeToString(data, Base64.NO_WRAP)` right? Instead it is `Base64.encodeToString(data, 3rd character and forth)`.

Comment: No. It is `Base64.encodeToString(data, Base64.NO_WRAP)`. However, `Base64.encodeToString(data, 2,1,Base64.NO_WRAP)` means encode 3rd and 4th character.

Comment: Okay thanks. Then what could be the reason for `Base64.encodeToString(data, 2)` not matching with `Base64.encodeToString(data, Base64.NO_WRAP)`?

Comment: Are you sure? can you paste the what is in the data? Also, post the 2 outputs.

Comment: Okay give me 30 minutes. It's a huge block of codes.